# How to update/create multiple records without going through another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have exercises, log_entries, and users.

Right now I can browse an exercise and I see a list of "log entries" which each one has data for "reps", and "weights."

In my controller I am updating `log_entries` by hitting the `exercises_controller` so it allows me to do bulk updating and saving with `accepts_nested_attributes_for.` However I feel something is broken here and wrong. Especially when I have to associate a `user_id` with each `log_entry`.

Is there a way I can handle this so I can update multiple records in a clean way, and using only the log_entries controller? It doesn't make logical sense for me to update log_entries by going through exercises, but maybe my semantics radar is off.

Here is the code that troubles me:

`exercises_controller.rb`

```
  def update
    @exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])

    recording_user_id = current_user.id
    recording_user_id = params[:user_id] if (params[:user_id].present? && User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]).is_a_client_of?(current_user))

    # associate the log_entries with either current user or client you're recording for.
    if params[:exercise].present? && params[:exercise][:log_entries_attributes].present?
      params[:exercise][:log_entries_attributes].each do |value|
        value[1].merge!(:user_id => recording_user_id)
      end
    end


    respond_to do |format|
      if @exercise.update_attributes(params[:exercise])
        format.html { redirect_to_back_or_default @exercise, notice: "Exercise was successfully updated." }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @exercise.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

How can I handle this in a more clean manner?

Answer (score 2):

You can make this quite a bit simpler if you change:

```
if @exercise.update_attributes(params[:exercise])
 ...
```

to:

```
@exercise.assign_attributes(params[:exercise])
@exercise.record_log_entries_as(recording_user_id)
if @exercise.save
  ...
```

and in your Exercise model:

```
def record_log_entries_as(user_id)
  log_entries.each{|entry| entry.user_id = user_id if entry.changed? || entry.new_record? }
end
```

This way you can update the collection in a more testable fashion without modifying the params hash.